# How to structure a multiple pages scrapy project, keeping single page implementation as independent as possible

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I want to scrap multiple webpages using scrapy. I already have a prototype but are not satisfied with the "maintenance" cost.

**How can I strucutre my scrapy project better, improving the following features:**

- Having an independent code base for each page (webpage) scraper
- Using "extraction methods" for multiple pages but maintaining it only ones, eg. page screenshot util, image downloader
- Testing "scraper" before full run (Unit test -> Is value returned)?
- If [Portia](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia) is mature, maybe use it if the Unit tests fail?

What do I have **currently**:

- I run my scraper via cron `crawl tagesschau` and `crawl spiegel`
- After the scraper is run, I run a second script fetching a screenshot of every new entry (bare python script using MySQL)

This lakes a testing if the scraper still works, and is hard to manage.

What can I do better?

Thank you,
-lony

P.S.: Scrapy was selected following [@elias advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714960/scraping-multiple-pages-staying-independent).

Comment: Btw, I am developing a spider project at work that may meet many of your desire, and I am about to open it on github in a month. it's has three parts: dispatcher, crawler, web. It's distributed based on rabbitmq. using mongodb to store the data, config, log,  and using memcached to filter duplication.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I want. I would be interested!

Comment: it's here zspider(https://github.com/Zephor5/zspider)

Comment: Nice, will you add a tutorial?